# How to connect ASP.NET app to remote SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config

I need help connecting my Web App to a remote database (SQL Server).
I have tried many suggested solutions but I can't seem to come right.

This is how I connect to a local database, it works 100%:

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=MVNE_Website;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My ASP.NET Web App is hosted on one server, and the database is on a separate server.

The remote DB server is 100% configured to allow remote connections and firewall rules also adhere to the connection protocols. I think it is just my connection string that is incorrect but I don't know why??

Here it is(conn string for remote SQL server)

```
<add name="DBCS" connectionString="server=serverIP\serverName; database=MVNE_Website; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I don't use a username or password when connecting to this remote SQL Server so I did not see a point in adding it in the conn string?

Comment: Should be `server=serverIP\InstanceName` or `server=serverName\InstanceName` not `serverIP\serverName`

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2004?

Comment: *2014, sorry... I will try all suggestions shortly, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:/

In my web.config file custom errors mode was on RemoteOnly, so I turned it off and saw that my connection string was never the problem, the actual problem was that the app was trying to insert null into a primary key field that does not allow null, i never set the PK to auto increment
.. sorry and thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few reasons why this will not work.  Here are 2 common ones:

1. Your web application will pass the username the application pool is running under, (which by default is some system user) to SQL Server.  Change this to be a service account which has access to SQL Server.
2. If you are hopping across 2 or more servers to pass the credentials between IIS and SQL Server, you may need to implement Kerberos, which is a way to preserve the credentials.  This is a complex network configuration thing.

Check point 1 first.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion(1) but it did not work for me? There has to be some kind of simple mistake that I am making because this SQL server is used by a number of websites so I think it is just my conn string that is incorrect but I don't know why? i have used the user id and password in the string (credentials have access and are correct) but still no luck? Can there be anything else that I am possibly missing?